# WebClient proxy configuration not working with oAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have implemented webclient and oAuth2 with grant type Client Credentials. I must use proxy to access bureau. But webclient is not using the host which I have configured.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
.tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
.doOnConnected(conn -> conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)))
.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyHost).port(proxyPort)));
```

**its working fine if I configure proxy with system :**

```
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "host);
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");
```

But I can't use System property over the cloud. Please suggest me some work around or any solution.

**I am getting below exception:**
"org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for \"https://tokenURL": api.uat.equifax.com; nested exception is java.net.**UnknownHostException**: resourseURL\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.getTokenResponse(DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.java:79)\r\n\tat ..."

Comment: the error msg is quite clear, Unknown host "https://tokenURL" that doesn't look like a valid hostname to me `"host` doesn't look valid

Comment: Thanks for your response Adolf, actually in my code I am using actual hostname but due to some security reason I am not pasting it over here. proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyHost).port(proxyPort))

Comment: well as i said before, the error msg is quite clear, UnknownHostException

Comment: Yes you are right Adolf but I don't get this unknownHostException when I set the proxies by using System.setProperty as mentioned above.  I do not want to set the proxies with System and I want to follow the conventional approach by setting the proxies with HttpClient alone. When we do this I get UnknownhostException. Suggest me some work around or any fix if possible.

Comment: my suggestion is to debug the application/source code and check what value actually is there when it throws the exception. Since the error does not lie in the code you have posted.

Comment: sure Andolf, thanks for your time and valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it was still the first stackoverflow entry we found so we decided to [document our solution](https://blog.doubleslash.de/spring-oauth2-client-authorization-request-proxy-support/).

We stumbled across the same problem. The exception **OAuth2AuthorizationException** indicates that the problem occurs during the authorization request. After some digging in the spring-security-oauth2-client sources, we found out that the authorization request is using a different client than the resource request. You only set the proxy for the resource client.

The authorization request is using a RestTemplate. The following code snippet shows how we created a custom RestTemplate that is using a proxy and added it to our OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.

```
@Bean 
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager( 
    final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, 
    final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) { 
 
    // Create RestTemplate that will be used for the authorization request
    // It's mandatory to add FormHttpMessageConverter and OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter
    // See javadoc from DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(RestOperations restOperations)
    // for further information
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate( 
        Arrays.asList(new FormHttpMessageConverter(), new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter())); 
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler()); 
 
 
    // set up proxy for RestTemplate
    final HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create(); 
    clientBuilder.useSystemProperties(); 
    clientBuilder.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyConfigDO.getHost(), proxyConfigDO.getPort())); 
 
    final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); 
    credsProvider.setCredentials( 
        new AuthScope(proxyConfigDO.getHost(), proxyConfigDO.getPort()), 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyConfigDO.getUser(), proxyConfigDO.getPassword())); 
    clientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider); 
    clientBuilder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy()); 
 
    final CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build(); 
    final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(); 
    factory.setHttpClient(client); 
 
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(factory)); 
 
    // Create new client and pass our custom resttemplate 
    final var tokenResponseClient = new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient(); 
    tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate); 
 
    // Create ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider and override default setAccessTokenResponseClient
    // with the one we created in this method
    final var authorizedClientProvider = new ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(); 
    authorizedClientProvider.setAccessTokenResponseClient(tokenResponseClient); 
 
    final var authorizedClientManager = 
        new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager( 
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService); 
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider); 
 
    return authorizedClientManager; 
}
```

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for sharing this. When I try your solution, I get the message: `a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.` I feel so close to the solution, but I do not understand why this bean is not created by spring based on my configuration (with the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration` set). Any idea?

Comment: Hi Purfakt, I'd guess that you're missing a spring dependency. We don't create the `ClientRegistrationRepository` bean manually.

Comment: it worked for  me, thanks ! I had to add this dependency : 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'