# confirming the proxy is used with Netty - issue with wiretap

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

My Spring Boot 2.7.1 application needs to use 2 different Oauth2 webclients, that each has its own identity provider. One of them needs to go through a proxy, but not the other.

For the one going through the proxy, I build it like this :

```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("systemA")
  WebClient getWebClientForSystemA(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager,
      @Value("${asset-sync-service.systemA-proxy.host}") String proxyHost,
      @Value("${asset-sync-service.systemA-proxy.port}") int proxyPort) {

    var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("systemA");

    var webClientBuilder=WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration());

    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(proxyHost)){

      log.info("setting proxy setting ({}:{}) on webclient for systemA webclient..",proxyHost,proxyPort);

      var httpClientWithSystemAProxy=HttpClient.create()
          .wiretap("systemAWebClient",LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
          .proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(Proxy.HTTP)
              .host(proxyHost)
              .port(proxyPort));

      webClientBuilder=webClientBuilder
          .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClientWithSystemAProxy));

    }

    return webClientBuilder.build();

  }
```

The first time the webClient is called and tries to get a token, it fails with :

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://systemA.my.company/connect/oauth2/access_token": systemA.my.company; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: systemA.my.company
```

(when I try access https://systemA.my.company/connect/oauth2/access_token in my browser, it gets resovled)

I added the wiretap in the HttpClient, because I have the feeling it's not going through the proxy, and I want to see more logs. But unfortunately, I don't see anything in my logs, despite setting Logback root logger at DEBUG level.

am I doing something wrong, either ín the wiretap config or in the config of the proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to fix the missing logs that I expect with wiretap, but the proxy issue is solved, thanks to

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65790535/3067542
- https://blog.doubleslash.de/spring-oauth2-client-authorization-request-proxy-support/

we need to configure the proxy also in the underlying restTemplate that is used by OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, in addition to configuring it in the webClient. Not obvious at all !